# Распределение чисел в процентном соотношении

Tags: php, алгоритм

есть партнеры которые привлекают клиентов на сайт.
на сайте есть учитываемый вид платежа(автоматический). и не учитываемый (ручной).

предположим что 4 партнера привлекли на сайт 150 клиентов в сумме.
из них по учитываемому виду платежа партнеры привлекли 5, 8, 1, 0 клиентов соответственно.

т.е. получается что через учитываемый вид платежа было совершено 5+8+1=14 покупок.

задача в следующем.
распределить все платежи на всех партнеров ориентируясь на учитываемый вид платежа.

например:
всего 14 сделок. первый партнер сделал 5 учитываемых сделок. получается что 5 - это ~35,71% от 14. 
а 35,71% от 150 - это 53,57. т.е. округляя мы получим что первый партнер совершил 53 сделки.

сначала я сделал так:

```
# исходный массив
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'count_pay' => '5',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'count_pay' => '8',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'count_pay' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'count_pay' => 0,
  ),
)

$vsego = 150;
$sum_of_done = 14;
$rows = array();
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    $value['raschet'] = floor($value['count_pay']*$vsego/$sum_of_done); // расчет и округление до целого
}

return $rows;
```

получается что каждый партнер сделал 53, 85, 10 и 0 сделок. в сумме = 148. 
остается 2 не распределенных.
если использовать round для округления. то будет 151.

как сделать распределение всей сумы 150 на каждого из партнеров?

Comment: Ну, вы сначала округляете, а потом жалуетесь на ошибку округления. Не округляйте, делов-то!

Comment: ну так в том то и дело. нужно же целое число.

Comment: Оставаясь в рамках целых чисел, невозможно. Вот вам пример попроще. 2 партнёра, 3 клиента в сумме, по одному учитываемому платежу. Как делить? Либо 1 и 1, в сумме 2. Либо 2 и 2, в сумме 4. Вывод: не морочьте голову и используйте нецелые числа.

Comment: ну да. получается что не возможно.. 
ладно. придется использовать дробные или выводить остаток отдельно..
спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вы перегоняете целые числа в проценты, а потом из процентов - обратно в целые числа?
Держите данные в каком-то одном виде (на мой взгляд в виде сделок, но я, кажется, что-то упустил в целях задачи) максимально доступное время. И проблема решится сама собой.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае подойдёт такая простая функция распределения:

```
/**
 * Метод выполняет пропорциональное распределение суммы в соответствии с заданными коэффициентами распределения.
 * @param float $sum Распределяемая сумма
 * @param array $arCoefficients Массив коэффициентов распределения, где ключи - определённые значения,
 *    которые также будут возвращены в виде ключей результирующего массива. Значения - величина коэффициента
 * @param int $precision Точность округления при распределении. Если передать 0,
 *    то все суммы после распределения будут целыми числами
 * @throws Exception Выбрасывается исключение в случае,
 *    если невозможно ровно распределить по заданным параметрам
 * @return array Массив, где сохранены ключи исходного массива $arCoefficients, а значения - сумма после распределения
 */
function getProportionalSums(float $sum, array $arCoefficients, int $precision) : array
{
    $arResult = [];

    /**
     * @var float Сумма значений всех коэффициентов
     */
    $sumCoefficients = 0.0;

    /**
     * @var float Значение максимального коэффициента по модулю
     */
    $maxCoefficient = 0.0;

    /**
     * @var mixed Ключ массива для максимального коэффициента по модулю
     */
    $maxCoefficientKey = null;

    /**
     * @var float Распределённая сумма
     */
    $allocatedAmount = 0;

    foreach ($arCoefficients as $keyCoefficient => $coefficient) {
        if (is_null($maxCoefficientKey)) {
            $maxCoefficientKey = $keyCoefficient;
        }

        $absCoefficient = abs($coefficient);
        if ($maxCoefficient < $absCoefficient) {
            $maxCoefficient = $absCoefficient;
            $maxCoefficientKey = $keyCoefficient;
        }
        $sumCoefficients += $coefficient;
    }
    if (!empty($sumCoefficients)) {
        foreach ($arCoefficients as $keyCoefficient => $coefficient) {
            $result = round(($sum * $coefficient / $sumCoefficients), $precision);

            $arResult[$keyCoefficient] = (0 === $precision) ? intval($result) : $result;

            $allocatedAmount += $result;
        }

        if ($allocatedAmount != $sum) {
            // Есть погрешности округления, которые надо куда-то впихнуть
            $tmpRes = $arResult[$maxCoefficientKey] + $sum - $allocatedAmount;

            // Погрешности округления отнесём на коэффициент с максимальным весом
            $arResult[$maxCoefficientKey] = (0 === $precision) ? intval($tmpRes) : $tmpRes;
        }
    }

    return $arResult;
}
```

Тут погрешность округления при распределении вносим в позицию с наибольшим коэффициентом. Вот проверка на ваших данных:

```
$arClient = [
    5,
    8,
    1,
    0
];
$arResult = getProportionalSums(150, $arClient, 0);
print_r($arResult);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 54
    [1] => 85
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 0
)
```

Как видно, сумма 150 полностью распределена пропорционально целочисленно (плюс первому, наибольшему клиенту досталось чуть больше).